# ASP.NET MVC2 JsonResult This request has been blocked

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc-2, jsonresult

I know the question is very familiar but i can't over it.

This is my Controller Action

```
public JsonResult AddToCart(int productId, int quantity = 1, int optionValue = 0)
{
  AjaxActionResponse res = new AjaxActionResponse();
  res.Result = ture;
  ......
  return Json(res, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

and this is my ajax request

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "<%= Url.Action("AddToCart", "CartAjax") %>",
    data: ({'productId': productId, 'quantity': quantity, 'optionValue': optionValue}),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (d) {
        if ($.isEmptyObject(d)) {
            return;
        }
        if (!d.Result) {
            alert(d.ErrorMessage[0].ErrorMessage);
        }
        else {
            $("#myCartBox").dialog("open");
        }
        return;
    }
});
```

when i run the ajax request known error pops up

> This request has been blocked because
>   sensitive information could be
>   disclosed to third party web sites
>   when this is used in a GET request. To
>   allow GET requests, set
>   JsonRequestBehavior to AllowGet.

I tried to making AddToCart action [HttpPost] acceptable but at this time: parameters never arrived the method and missing argument error returned from the request (500 int. serv error)

I can run only with get method but request has been blocked at this time :)

Am i missing something? Or what is the right way for MVC2 Ajax request. WebForms was very successfully about calling methods from JavaScript but i couldn't do that on MVC.

Any Idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using POST using this method signature?

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddToCart(FormCollection form)
```

Or using databinding:

```
public class CartItem {
    public int productId {get; set;}
    public int quantity {get; set;}
    public int optionValue {get; set;}
}
```

Then:

```
 public ActionResult AddToCart(CartItem c)
```

Unfortunately I don't have a *good* answer, but I've solved some of my own problems this way (rather than figure out how to get the parameters passed nicely using routes).

Comment: Oh my god it works :) I think, Model binding is the right way for this kind requests. Thank you very much @mootinator and other participants :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know for certain that this is your fundamental issue, but you shouldn't set the content-type to text/html.  That isn't what you're sending or what MVC expects.  Omit that parameter altogether, and let jQuery set it to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, which is appropriate.

Comment: Umm yes you are right but it was just trying. The first version of my code has "application/json" content type but nothing was different.

Comment: application/json would be incorrect too. That data parameter won't be sent to the server as JSON. Try omitting the content-type; jQuery sets it right automatically for regular urlencoded requests.

Comment: actually you can omit the `contentType` entirely and let the jQuery set it.

Comment: I did it but nothing changed :(

Comment: Are you sure that the request is being routed to the controller action that you think it is? That's been a gotcha that plagued me in the past. Since the routes are "greedy", it's easy to run into that. If your request was being routed to the wrong action, it would make sense that adding the AllowGet to this one would result in the same error.